# Upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04. Command line says /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk. How do I upgrade from here?

Tags: upgrade

From 18.04 Release Notes downloaded 18.04 iso then tried this in Terminal: `Alt F2 update-manager -c`

Got:

```
No command 'Alt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'slt' from package 'slt' (universe)
 Command 'lt' from package 'looptools' (universe)
 Command 'llt' from package 'storebackup' (universe)
Alt: command not found
```

So typed in this command in Terminal: `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk`. Got:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING:root:found new dist 'bionic' but it is on the ignore list
```

I seem to be stuck now.  How do I download 18.04 LTS from here?

Comment: You have to press ALT+F2 to open Run command dialog. And then type `update-manager -c` in the field. Or open terminal with CTRL+ALT+T and execute `update-manager -c` here.

Comment: Tried this.  It just says Command not found.

Comment: You don't download the 18.04 ISO to upgrade; the commands are executed on your *xenial* or 16.04 box which will cause it to download required packages & perform the upgrade.  You've not said if this is a desktop or server install; but desktop installs are easily upgraded via re-install; servers need some config files to be restored so it's not usually done with server systems. Are you asking about a server install? desktop install?  Are you running the upgrade commands on your 16.04 system?